# Docker mounted Spring Webclient java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-webflux, webclient

i am facing a very weird situation with spring webflux, completablefuture and docker.
please help and if you need more code please comment below.

what i am doing is connecting to an external api to fetch data from it. the code works fine in local but provides following error when mounted onto docker.

```
2024-02-19T14:23:00.328Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: completableFuture completionException occured] with root cause
2024-02-19 23:23:00 
2024-02-19 23:23:00 java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:166) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.104.Final.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.handleConnectErrno(Errors.java:131) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.104.Final.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:359) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.104.Final.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:711) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.104.Final.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:688) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.104.Final.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:567) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.104.Final.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.104.Final.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:407) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.104.Final.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.104.Final.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.104.Final.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.104.Final.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
2024-02-19 23:23:00     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
```

the above is the error that is provided. following is the code that triggers

```
 public List<List<BaseResponseItem>> concurrentPreGetFromApi(Address address) {
        // Create CompletableFutures for each API call
        CompletableFuture<List<BaseResponseItem>> baseFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                baseApiService.fetchAllBaseData(address));

        // Execute the other three tasks in the background after baseFuture is complete
        CompletableFuture<Void> sideEffectTasks = baseFuture.thenRunAsync(() -> {
            log.info("running start sideEffectTasks");
            log.info("running start sideEffectTasks exposInfo");
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    exposedInfoApiService.fetchAllExposedInfoData(address);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error in fetchAllExposedInfoData", e);
                }
                return null;
            });
            log.info("running start sideEffectTasks recaptitle");
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                recapTitleService.fetchAllRecapTitleData(address);
                return null; // dummy result
            });
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                titleApiService.fetchAllTitleData(address);
                return null; // dummy result
            });
        });

        try {
            // Retrieve the results from the completed CompletableFutures
            List<BaseResponseItem> baseResponseItemList = baseFuture.join();
            // Your business logic with the retrieved lists
            List<BaseResponseItem> baseResponseTitleItemList = baseApiService.fetchAllTitleBaseData(baseResponseItemList);
            List<BaseResponseItem> baseResponseExposItemList = baseApiService.fetchAllExposInfoBaseData(baseResponseItemList);

            if(baseResponseTitleItemList.isEmpty() && baseResponseExposItemList.isEmpty()) {
                return new LinkedList<>(List.of(baseResponseItemList));
            }
            return new LinkedList<>(List.of(baseResponseTitleItemList,baseResponseExposItemList));

        }
        catch (CompletionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("completableFuture completionException occured",e);
        }
    }
```

each of the completableFuture runs a block of code similar to the following

```
  @Cacheable(value= "fetchAllBaseData")
    public List<BaseResponseItem> fetchAllBaseData(Address address) {
        // Check if the data is already in the cache
        Cache.ValueWrapper valueWrapper = Objects.requireNonNull(cacheManager.getCache("fetchAllBaseData")).get(address);

        // Use the address as a key for the lock
        ReentrantLock fetchLock = addressLocks.computeIfAbsent(address, k -> new ReentrantLock());

        // Acquire the lock
        fetchLock.lock();
        try {
            // Double-check if the value is inside the cache
            if (valueWrapper != null) {
                // Data is updated in cache
                return (List<BaseResponseItem>) valueWrapper.get();
            }

            // Fetch data from the API
            return fetchDataFromApi(address);
        } finally {
            // Release the lock
            fetchLock.unlock();
            addressLocks.remove(address, fetchLock);
        }
    }


    public List<BaseResponseItem> fetchDataFromApi(Address address) {
        int total = totalPages(address);
        log.warn("totalPages : {}", total);
        return Flux.range(1, total)
                .flatMap(page -> {
                    log.info("currpage {}", page);
                    return fetchPageData(address, page);
                }, CONCURRENCYLIMIT)  // Fetch data for each page
                .collectList()
                .block();  // Block and wait for the result
   }

    private Flux<BaseResponseItem> fetchPageData(Address address, int pageNo) {
        WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> request = apiService.getRequestHeadersSpec(address, BaseApiServiceAsync.URI, pageNo);
        Mono<BaseApiResponse> apiResponseMono = request.retrieve().bodyToMono(BaseApiResponse.class);

        return apiResponseMono
//                .doOnNext(apiResponse -> log.info("Received API response: {}", apiResponse))
                .flatMapMany(apiResponse -> Flux.fromIterable(apiResponse.getResponse().getBody().getItems().getItem()))
                .doOnError(error -> {
                    log.error("Error fetching BASE data for page {}", pageNo, error);
                    if (error instanceof WebClientResponseException) {
                        String responseBody = ((WebClientResponseException) error).getResponseBodyAsString();
                        String errorCode = ((WebClientResponseException) error).getStatusCode().toString();
                        log.error("Response body: {} . errorcode: {}", responseBody, errorCode);
                    }
                }).retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                        .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof WebClientException)
                );

    }

    private Integer totalPages(Address address) {
        WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> request = apiService.getRequestHeadersSpec(address, URI, 1);
        String responseString = request.retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
        log.info("totalPages at {}, ", responseString);
        BaseApiResponse apiResponse = request.retrieve().bodyToMono(BaseApiResponse.class).block();

        assert apiResponse != null;
        int totalCount = apiResponse.getResponse().getBody().getTotalCount();
        int repeats = (int) Math.ceil((double) totalCount / WebClientApiService.SAFE_QUERY);
        log.warn("totalcount {}, repeats : {}", totalCount, repeats);
        return repeats;
    }
```

this is the dockerfile used to create the image

```
# Stage 1: Build JRE
FROM eclipse-temurin:21 as jre-build
#RUN $JAVA_HOME/bin/jlink \
#         --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH \
#         --strip-debug \
#         --no-man-pages \
#         --no-header-files \
#         --compress=2 \
#         --output /javaruntime

# Stage 2: Final Image
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Install required packages in a single RUN command
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y curl \
    && apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set Java environment variables
ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk
ENV PATH "${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"

# Copy JRE from the build stage
# COPY --from=jre-build /javaruntime $JAVA_HOME
COPY --from=jre-build /opt/java/openjdk $JAVA_HOME

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir /opt/app

# Copy the JAR file to the app directory
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /opt/app/firefacilauto.jar

# Copy entrypoint script
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# Give execute permission to the entrypoint script
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

# Set entry point for the application
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 8080 80

# Add metadata to the image
LABEL authors="user"
```

entrypoint.sh has the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
exec java -jar /opt/app/firefacilauto.jar
```

network connected has the following. redis cache -> using @Cacheable also uses the same network

```
        "Networks": {
            "RedisForSpringBoot": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "78c9aa26a371"
                ],
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "NetworkID": "17bc7512075a0643987824388acb2da06e0b81fe18f5614df3f5f4c24fe22167",
                "EndpointID": "a9d6d250881aa521379a9c66a5bee1596daf5b27480313a4bd1f2eb30e661803",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.18.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "DriverOpts": null,
                "DNSNames": [
                    "firefacilauto",
                    "78c9aa26a371"
                ]
            }
        }
```

very strange as when i tried curl to the external service in exec, the request can pass through to host but webclient cannot.
i did not configure any proxies so if there is one it comes out implicit but i am not too sure about that.

have been struggling on this for the past 36 hours. send help

explained above,

tldr:

1. rebuilt docker image commenting out various portions of the dockerfile code
2. tried curl to the actual service to test connectivity which passed so it excludes docker network issues
3. enabled netty.io logging at debug to receive debug message which is too verbose so is left out, will be provided upon request